# Definition of submanifolds by regular values

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f: M \rightarrow N$ and $q \in N$ be a regular value, then $f^{-1}(q)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

Now assume that $q \in N$ is not a regular value, but you pick $K:=f^{-1}(q) \cap \{p \in M; Df|_p \text{ is surjective.}\}.$ Does this mean that $K$ is a manifold? Or more generally, is there a way out to define a manifold if our $q$ is not a regular value?

Comment: Yes. This is a local question  around each point of $K$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $U = \{x\in M : Df|_x\text{ is surjective}\}$ is open in $M$. Thus it is a manifold. If you restrict $f$ to $U$, then

$$K = (f|_U)^{-1}(q)$$

Thus $K$ is a manifold and is a submanifold in $U$.

Comment: would you still mind taking a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347642/wrong-pushforward-of-vector-field-definition-on-wikipedia cause somehow I think that either I don't understand the answer I got or there is another underlying problem.

Comment: Why is this not a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$? No one says submanifolds must be closed subsets!

Comment: @TedShifrin : Thanks! That's my misunderstanding.